# Saving Values in a .txt document using QB64

Tags: save, qb64

In my Text based Adventure game using QB64, in attempting to save the players name they put in, the age they put in and the gender they selected. no errors come up, but when I check the Text Document, all it puts in is a 0.
 i'm calling the sub after they put the info in, so the variables are already set.

```
SUB saving


save1.txt$ = "save1.txt"
OPEN save1.txt$ FOR APPEND ACCESS WRITE AS #1 LEN = 40
PRINT #1, name$
PRINT #1, age%
PRINT #1, gender$


CLOSE #1

end sub
```

Comment: Let show us how/where you call the subroutine `saving`. I see that this subroutine has no parameters. Did you share the variables: `name$`, `age%`, `gender$`?

Comment: I suggest you to save age% with `PRINT #1, str$(age%)`. I think it's better you use separator between the values on the file and you write all data of record on the same line. Your code, now, uses three lines to write that which should be a record. IMHO, is better to use something such a ',' or '; ' to separate fields of each record. Then you may write `PRINT #1, name$; ";"; str$(age%);";";gender$`

Comment: thank you, but i was able to get it to save `
SUB saving





   ` OPEN "save1.txt" FOR OUTPUT AS #1`
  `  PRINT Name$`
   ` PRINT age%`
   ` PRINT gender$`
   ` PRINT #1, Name$`
   ` PRINT #1, age%`
   ` PRINT #1, gender$`




    `CLOSE #1`






`END SUB` @SirJoBlack

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variables to write to file to the Saving subroutine:

```
PRINT "Enter name";: INPUT name$
PRINT "Enter age";: INPUT age%
PRINT "Enter gender";: INPUT gender$
CALL Saving(name$, age%, gender$)
END
SUB Saving (name$, age%, gender$)
    Save1.Txt$ = "save1.txt"
    OPEN Save1.Txt$ FOR APPEND AS #1
    PRINT #1, name$
    PRINT #1, age%
    PRINT #1, gender$
    CLOSE #1
END SUB
```

Or you could declare the variables as shared as such:

```
DIM SHARED username AS STRING
DIM SHARED age AS INTEGER
DIM SHARED gender AS STRING
PRINT "Enter name";: INPUT username
PRINT "Enter age";: INPUT age
PRINT "Enter gender";: INPUT gender
CALL Saving
END
SUB Saving
    Save1.Txt$ = "save1.txt"
    OPEN Save1.Txt$ FOR APPEND AS #1
    PRINT #1, username
    PRINT #1, age
    PRINT #1, gender
    CLOSE #1
END SUB
```